# Python matching pathnames that include an element from a list

Tags: python, glob

I have a list of numbers ['2054', '3271', '8671', '273'] and would like to find all files in a directory that include any one of those values in the pathname in a set pattern. I am using the glob module to find all the pathnames but I have not found a good way of including the numbers from my list. This is what I have so far:

```
pathPac = '/Users/noah/Data/Docs'
pathlist = Path(pathPac).glob('**/doc*.xml')
```

But instead of doc*.xml I want to find a way of looking for doc2054.xml, doc3271.xml and so on. I have looked around in the glob documentation, but have not found anything to do this.

Comment: Iterate through the resulting list and check if either of your numbers are present in the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create list of directories using that list

```
pathPac = '/Users/noah/Data/Docs'
suffixes = ['2054', '3271', '8671', '273']
candidates = [Path(pathPac).glob(f'**/doc{i}.xml') for i in suffixes]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not (easily*) possible with globs.  Either post-process the glob, or just use a regex search directly.  In this case I'd probably post-process:

```py
pathPac = '/Users/noah/Data/Docs'
candidates = Path(pathPac).glob('**/doc*.xml')
suffixes = ['2054', '3271', '8671', '273']
for f in (c for c in candidates if any(s in c.stem for s in suffixes)):
    do_something(f)
```

This is Not Very Efficient (loops within loops).  I highly doubt you will notice unless you have several TB of data, or suffixes is much longer than you suggest.

*you could generate globs using string munging and then concatenate them.  That scores quite high on my 'this is a hack' scale.

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway to use c.stem or an alternative to make sure just the values from suffixes are searched and a file like doc205432.xml is not included? Or does this require a regex search?

Comment: Use c.suffix if you want to match in the suffix

Comment: However if you want to check for an exact match before the . Use a regex on the stem or check for `stem[-1] == c[-1]`